# Socket.io Client Request Origin URL

Tags: sockets, node.js, client, socket.io

On the client, in the browser, I have this code:

```
this.socket.on('initial', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

On the server I have:

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('client connected');
});
```

My question is: how can I detect the URL where the request came from? For example if the first closure was running on "/posts/view/1", I want to be able to detect it inside of the second closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send this data back to the server. A little hand-wavey on the details, but how about something like:

On the client:

```
this.socket.on('initial', function(data) {
  // do whatever with data
  var my_location = get_page_location_with_javascript(); // or whatever
  this.socket.emit('phone_home', my_location);
});
```

On the server:

```
this.sockets.on('phone_home', function(url) {
  console.log("The URL was " + url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is what I just started implementing before I read your reply :D. I wish there was a built-in way of doing this.

Comment: So, I just finished implementing this thing and it seems to work well. I used jQuery URL Parser to split the url into chunks that I needed: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser.

Comment: I'm doing something similar to this. But speaking about validation, and security, i feel it's a little unsafe to use like this. The client can control whatever data he sends. Could you suggest me something about this, or a brief about how this is safe to use ?