# Determine URL of client request from server side. Socket.io

Tags: cross-domain, socket.io-1.0

Ref: [Socket.io Client Request Origin URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422157/socket-io-client-request-origin-url)

Ref: [Socket.io - How to get client URL request on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239695/socket-io-how-to-get-client-url-request-on-server-side)

How do you determine the URL of client request from server side? Client request may come from multiple domains.

Comment: Do you mean the URL of the client page that is attempting to do a socket.io connection to your server at the server when the connection request arrives?  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeap, that's what is required. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

socket.io stores the request object from the original request that initiated the socket.io connection in `socket.request`.

On this `request` object is:

```
request.url
request.headers
```

The `.url` property will be the path of the URL (everything after the protocol, hostname and port).

The `.headers` property will contain any headers on the original request.  In a cooperating browser, if the request is a cross origin request, then there will be an `origin` header that tells you what the domain was of the web page that the request was initiated from (it may also be present on a same-origin request too).  This "origin" header will be accurate when coming from a trusted browser such as Chrome, IE, Safari, Firefox, etc..., but can easily be spoofed if coming from any other sort of agent (such as another server or script).